# Vue routing and navigation guard not routing properly

Tags: authentication, axios, vuejs3, vue-router, vite

I am trying to implement router guard on my homepage. User is routed to the login page from the homepage if they are not authenticated. It works fine but the problem is when i try to login after being redirected to the login page. Once i click on my login button i do not get routed to my homepage instead I remain on the login page, but it shows that i have been authenticated.

This is my code in my navigation guard

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const store = useAuthStore(pinia)
  if (to.name !== 'login' && !store.isAuthenticated) {
    next({ name: 'login' })
  } else{
    next()
  }
})
```

and this is the code for logging in, in my store

```
async function handleSubmit() {
        isLoading.value = true
        if(pageType.value == 'signUp' && name.value != '' && email.value != '' && password.value != ''){
            await axios.post(url.value, {
                name: name.value,
                email: email.value,
                password: password.value
            })
            .then(() => {
                pageType.value = "login"
                isLoading.value = false
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err.response.data.message);
            })
        }else if(pageType.value == 'login' && email.value != '' && password.value != ''){
            await axios.post(`${url.value}/login`, {
                email: email.value,
                password: password.value
            })
            .then( (res) => {
                isLoading.value = false
                const token = res.data.token;
                localStorage.setItem('token', token);
                axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
                axios.get(`${url.value}/me`)
                    .then((res) => {
                        setUser(res.data)
                        router.push('/')                  
                        console.log(router.push('/'));
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.log(err);
                    })
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            })
        }
    }
```

this is the computed property i use to check if a user is authenticated or not

```
const isAuthenticated = computed(() => {
       return !!user.value
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const store = useAuthStore(pinia)
  if (to.name !== 'login' && !store.isAuthenticated) {
    next({ name: 'login' })
  } else if (to.name === 'login' && store.isAuthenticated) {
    next({ path: '/' })
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

Redirects `{ name: 'login' }` to `{ path: '/' }` when `store.isAuthenticated` is `true`.

**Notes:**

- I'm guessing `next({ path: '/' })` takes the users where you want them to go. If that's not the case, replace accordingly.
- *"smarter"* routing solutions save the initially requested route in store, before redirecting to `/login` and, once the user has authenticated, use the saved value to send them on the route they requested initially.

Comment: this doesn't work but changes the behaviour, once i try to login it shows that i am authenticated, but does not route to the home page until i refresh.  And how do i go about the second note?

Comment: ***a)*** I can't help more with what you've shared. Consider providing a *runnable* [mcve] using condesandbox.io (or similar). You don't have to include your entire project and I suggest mocking the authentication part with a delayed promise. But I need see at least the router setup with at least the login and the home pages. and ***b)*** on [so] you ask each question separately. If I gave you an answer for the second note here, it wouldn't be as helpful for future users.